# Renaming a CoreData Entity, representedClassName does not get renamed

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

Using Xcode 6.2 and CoreData.  I needed to rename a couple of entity names and recreate the NSManaged objects and noticed that the New Managed objects did not get named the same as the new entity names - the old name was used.

Here's some output from diff on the data model contents file:

```
-    <entity name="SavedSignSets" representedClassName="SavedSignSets" syncable="YES">
+    <entity name="SavedSignSet" representedClassName="SavedSignSets" syncable="YES">
```

This a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

**UPDATE:**
Exact problem is this:

1. I had an existing entity and corresponding managed object generated by Xcode 6.2.  Entity and managed object had the same name.
2. I changed the Entity name.
3. I trashed the corresponding managed object files.
4. Using Xcode 6.2 I generate Managed Object for the entity - assuming the new name will be used
5. Xcode names the managed object using the old entity name.

Comment: It's not completely clear what problem you're seeing. Is the problem with the class name of new managed object instances, or with the entity name? Describe the problem you're actually seeing in more detail.

Comment: Entity Name is not same as the Class Name. The Class Name is defaulted to the Entity Name when the Entity is first created, but they can be different if you wish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

select the entity and check the entity inspector in the utilities view's data model inspector (the left left menu), each entity has a name field and a class field. When you change the name in the GUI you only change the class name. To correct the error you to change the name as well.

Answer (score 0):

The core data framework is a little finnicky in XCode. It has seemed to get confused in overwriting existing auto-generated files. I can't guarantee this is a fix, but you can try manually trashing your old Managed Object class file(s) from the XCode Navigation window (make sure you delete, and not just remove reference), and then creating the NSManagedObject subclass again under the guise of it being a new file.

In doing this, also manually check that any Relationship references in other files get updated with the new class name as well (sometimes they will load as the generic NSManagedObject class on one side of the relationship). It was taught to me as standard practice to trash the whole set of generated entity files and recreate them as a group.

(Also, I'm running XCode 6.1.1 so I'm not on your exact version)

Comment: I tried both trashing the whole set Managed Objects and just the ones I had changed - didn't make a difference.  I ended up editing the xcdatamodel/contents file directly to make the change to the representedClassName setting for the entity in question.  Also made sure relationship references were correct (they were).  I'm going to file a bug on this.